# Mod rewrite not rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following file structure:

```
/testrest/
/testrest/.htaccess
/testrest/index.php
```

My `index.php` file simple echoes text to the screen to confirm that the rewrite has pointed to that file.

My `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /testrest/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

..but after I restart Apache, it doesn't rewrite the URL

E.g: `http://:localhost/testrest/categories/`

(I'm expecting to see the index file) What am I doing wrong?

Btw I can confirm that Mod rewrite is enable (as seen when I do `phpinfo()` )

Comment: You don't need to restart apache when modifying a .htaccess file (that's kind of the point of them). In what way does it not work? You probably do not need `RewriteBase`.

Comment: Does your apache config allow .htaccess files?

Comment: Yes, Linux. I'm on Ubuntu Server. I just figure as mod_rewrite was enabled then it allows .htaccess. Is this not the case?

Comment: Edit your .htaccess and add this code `Options +FollowSymLinks` top of your file and try.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess in `/testrest/categories/` path?

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out how to build a RESTful API web service. Categories folder doesn't exist, I want the URL to be rewritten to index.php and the path set as the request parameter.